# java.net.MalformedURLException: Cannot retrieve ActionForward

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

I am trying to learn the Apache Struts framework and I have written a small application that does class enrollments but whenever I try and load up my application it just spits out the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot create redirect URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: Cannot retrieve ActionForward named HelloWorld
```

My index.jsp page looks like:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"% >
<logic:redirect forward="helloWorld"/ >
```

The relevant parts of my struts-config.xml:

```
<form-beans>
        <form-bean name="HelloWorldForm" type="com.Form.HelloWorldAction" />
</form-beans>

<global-forwards>
</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>
    <action name="HelloWorldForm" path="/helloWorld" type="com.Form.HelloWorldAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/Success.jsp" />
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

HelloWorldAction Page looks like:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, 
                        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws Exception {

    HelloWorldForm Hw = (HelloWorldForm) form;
    Hw.setMessage("Hello World");

    return mapping.findForward("success");
```

Success Page looks like:

```
<bean:write name="HelloWorldForm" property="message"/ >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<logic:redirect forward="HalloWorld"/ >
```

First, there's no forward named `HalloWorld`, only `helloWorld`.

Second, the bean is named `HalloWorldForm` and the action uses `HelloWorldForm`--not the problem, but it will be once the first one is fixed.

Comment: Hi Dooo NoooN, I have done correction you made but still i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<global-forwards>
        <forward name="helloWorld" path="/helloWorld.do"/>

</global-forwards>
```